# Tkinter returning 0 from curl command

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm attempting to hit a URL via curl with the following command:

```
curl -s http://path.to.url.com/
```

The expected outcome is something along the lines of

```
'{"ResponseCode":"SUCCESS","information":"info"}'
```

I'm attempting to have a tkinter box display the outcome of the curl command, but it's only outputting 0.

Using python normally, I see the regular return without issue. My script looks something like this (some data redacted).

```
results=os.system("curl -s http://path.to.url.com/")
        Label(mGui,text=str(results)).place(x = 10, y = 10 )
```

The above will create a box in the tkinter window that only returns 0

Comment: `os.system()` returns the exit code, not the actual stdout output. Take a look at `Popen`

Comment: The return value of `os.system()` is merely the status of the execution - this function does not give you any access to the standard input/output of the command.  You want one of the various function in the `subprocess` module to do that.

Comment: Looks like you're all correct. changing the results to `subprocess.check_output("curl -s http://path.to.url.com/")` works perfectly. Thanks again!

Comment: this has nothing to do with tkinter, tkinter is just displaying what you're telling it to.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're all correct. changing the results to `subprocess.check_output("curl -s http://path.to.url.com/")` works perfectly. Thanks again!